# Specifying wildcards in a MSVC module definition file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ld

With LD version scripts, it's possible to specify symbols to be exported via wildcard patterns. But I cannot find how to do the same with MSVC module definition (.def) files.

e.g. With the following version script, `getFoo` along with all symbols inside `mynamespace::bar::` will be exported while all other symbols will be hidden.

```
{
  global:
    getFoo;
    extern "C++" {
      mynamespace::bar::*;
    };
  local: *;
};
```

With a .def file, I can get `getFoo` exported with an `EXPORTS` statement in the .def file; but how can I achieve the same effect of exporting everything inside `mynamespace::bar::`? Is there a way to get the MSVC linker to recognize wildcard patterns?

Note that I don't necessarily need to make this work with a .def file per se. If I can somehow get the MSVC linker to recognize the version script that is fine too. However, when I try to do this
with a `-Wl,--version-script=libfoo.map` linker flag, MSVC complains about not recognizing this option.